# Tracking clicks of guest users, with some decent kind of uniqueness

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

Please be advised, this is not a code-problem question.

I have a resource in my app that is available only for authenticated users. In case a guest user tries to access the resource by clicking on it - registration modal shows up.

Now, I'm building logic using jQuery and PHP in order to **store those clicks of guests**. However, I also would like to implement something, that will let me **retrieve rough information on unique users** among the ones who clicked.

The idea I have is this:

1. When a specific page is loaded, set a JS cookie of "unique" value,
   like this: `[random string of fixed size][timestamp]`. The cookie
   would expire in a year from now. If the cookie already exists, don't
   do anything.
2. When the guest clicks on the resource, make an Ajax
       call to store the click AND the cookie value.
3. Later, to get "unique" clicks, make a `SELECT` that will `GROUP BY`
   the cookie value.

Unless the cookies are cleared or the custom cookie expiration date is exceeded, this should give me a way to determine unique clicks (users) among guests.

I'm interested, if anyone can provide me with a better way to achieve what I need.

Comment: That will work just as good as any other. One other option is to skip the cookie and just grab their IP address ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']). Both solutions have drawbacks, I.E. Someone could clear their cookies regulary or set it up to save no cookies at all and inflate your numbers. On the other side someone could easily spoof their IP address, and IP addresses typically change once a month for most internet providers. Maybe a solution incorporating both?

Comment: That's some solution right there, but after taking a look at whet Google Analytics provides out of the box (see answer of @Axel Amthor below) - I think I'll stick to that.

Comment: I don't blame you, the implementation is infinitely easier. Heads up, GA is a purely cookie based system so your numbers will still be slightly skewed and users who manipulate their cookies (via incognito mode/manual deletion/session only cookies) will mess the data up slightly. GA is still the best solution, just thought you should know some of the limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't reinvent the wheel and use Google Analytics for this kind of task, since it's almost doing al the job and giving you nice graphics and statistics for free.

Comment: Thanks. But in this case, we're not talking about a page with a URL. It's about getting clicks on a specific part of page. Clicking on it does not lead the user to a page, but provides a dynamic feature OR shows a registration modal. How can I track that with Analytics?

Comment: I got this! This can be achieved with Google Analytics easily, see here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide